# Spark - How to handle dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new dev about spark,I need your help, My issue, I read file from csv. And in csv file I have more row have format is `[logDate, id]`

Example:

```
2017-01-11 09:00:00, a
2017-01-11 09:30:00, b
2017-01-11 08:00:00, b
```

I want dataframe after handle will structure as `[lastLoginDate, id, firstLoginDate]`.

Result expected is: `(2017-01-11 09:30:00, a, 2017-01-11 09:00:00) (2017-01-11 08:00:00, b,2017-01-11 08:00:00)`.

Now, I have one solution but I want to find faster way. I read csv file in dataframe. After that I sort dataframe by id and log_date in 2 way (asc and desc). Finally, I join 2 dataframe that I have from sorting to get fields last login date and first login date.

And my schema is

```
|-- game_code: string (nullable = true) 
|-- last_login_date: string (nullable = true) 
|-- register_date: string (nullable = true) 
|-- id: string (nullable = true) 
|-- sid: string (nullable = true) 
|-- os: string (nullable = true) 
|-- devive: string (nullable = true) 
|-- deviceId: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution to be... How slow is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `first` and `last` inbuilt functions to get the final dataframe you require as

```
df.orderBy("logDate").groupBy("id").agg(last("logDate").as("lastLoginDate"), first("logDate").as("firstLoginDate"))
```

You should get the result as

```
+---+---------------------+---------------------+
|id |lastLoginDate        |firstLoginDate       |
+---+---------------------+---------------------+
| a |2017-01-11 09:00:00.0|2017-01-11 09:00:00.0|
| b |2017-01-11 09:30:00.0|2017-01-11 08:00:00.0|
+---+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

You can include the rest of the columns in the aggregation if you want them all as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.orderBy("last_login_date").groupBy("id")
  .agg(first("last_login_date").as("firstLoginDate"),
    last("last_login_date").as("lastLoginDate"),
    first("game_code").as("game_code"),
    first("register_date").as("register_date"),
    first("sid").as("sid"),
    first("os").as("os"),
    first("devive").as("devive"),
    first("deviceId").as("deviceId"))
  .show(false)
```

Note: you can go ahead and try using `Window` function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However I think I can't use this solution because in my question I still not present full format. Beside id and logDate I have other fields as ip, device,..If use aggession I only get id,last login date and register date. Once again, thanks for your support.

Comment: can you post the schema of your table then? so that I or somebody else can help you with that.

Comment: My schema is |-- game_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_login_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- register_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- os: string (nullable = true)
 |-- devive: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deviceId: string (nullable = true)

Comment: for the rest of the columns, do you want the first value or the last value?

Comment: Actually, first value and last value of other column is equal. Therefore, we can get first or last. I only handle first and last at 2 fields are last_login_date and register_date that you suggest solution to handle.

Comment: see my updated answer :) there is one confusion though. your schema doesn't have LogDate but in o/p you have used it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It exactly that I find

Comment: did it help? if the answer helped then please upvote and accept it :)

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score" Sorry, I can't upvote